Snowflake INSERT INTO only inserting the last row of UDTF output?
I was able to write a script in Snowflake that accesses an API and returns multiple rows from a UDTF (and plan on using Tasks to schedule and automate the API requests). However, when trying to insert the resulting table into my RAW table, the insert statement only inserts the last row of data into RAW.
Basically, this SQL code successfully pings the API and returns all rows of data:
SELECT m.* 
FROM MSA_CODES_API_TESTING, 
TABLE(pull_MSA_returns(MSA_CODE)) as m;

But when trying to use this insert into statement, only the last row is inserted:
INSERT INTO RAW.MARKET_DATA
SELECT m.* 
FROM MSA_CODES_API_TESTING, 
TABLE(pull_MSA_returns(MSA_CODE)) as m;

Same result occurs with:
INSERT INTO RAW.MARKET_DATA
WITH downloaded_api_data AS (
    SELECT m.* 
    FROM MSA_CODES_API_TESTING, 
    TABLE(pull_MSA_returns(MSA_CODE)) as m)
SELECT * FROM downloaded_api_data;

Any thoughts on why this might be failing to add all rows (instead of inserting the last one)?  I'd ideally like to use the INSERT statement without having to specify all columns.
(Specifying all columns doesn't appear to help either)
INSERT INTO RAW.MARKET_DATA
    (MSA_CODE,
    MSA_NAME,
    CAGR_1,
    DATE_ACCESSED)
WITH downloaded_api_data AS (
    SELECT m.* 
    FROM MSA_CODES_API_TESTING, 
    TABLE(pull_MSA_returns(MSA_CODE)) as m)
SELECT * FROM downloaded_api_data;

*And yes, the RAW.MARKET_DATA table has the same columns as the resulting UDTF.

Checking query profile can shed some light on that. Does the same occur when using CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp AS SELECT m.* FROM MSA_CODES_API_TESTING,      TABLE(pull_MSA_returns(MSA_CODE)) as m; and INSERT INTO RAW.MARKET_DATA SELECT * FROM temp?

Oh wow, your suggestion worked! I would love to understand why using INSERT INTO RAW.MARKET_DATA SELECT m.*  FROM MSA_CODES_API_TESTING,  TABLE(pull_MSA_returns(MSA_CODE)) as m; didn't work.  Maybe it's due to the way UDTF returns the result, making it different from creating a temporary table? Either way, running the two queries you mentioned above worked, thank you!
